Statistical bounds on number of digits for an element from a Fibonacci-like sequence
consider the following sequence $\{T_{k}\}$ defined as
$$
T_{k} = T_{k-1} + T_{k-2},\quad T_{k}\in\mathbb{N},\quad k>1 \tag{1}
$$
with given $n$ and $T_{n}=p$
I am interested in finding a relation between the number of digits of an element $T_{k}$ from this sequence using what's given. In particular, I wish to approximate the number of digits of the initial term $T_{0}$.
I tried to establish a relation between what we know about the standard Fibonacci sequence. We know that the standard Fibonacci sequence can be written as
$$
F_{n}=\left\lceil\frac{((1+\sqrt{5})/2)^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}\right\rceil
$$
Now define
$$
A:=\log(1+\sqrt{5})/2
$$
Then the number of digits for the $n-$th Fibonacci term is
$$
L_{F}(n)=\lceil nA-\log(5/2)\rceil
$$
I will now attempt to establish a connection to derive $L_{T}(n)$. One thing I noted is that the general solution to the linear recurrence defined in $(1)$ can be shown to be
$$
T_{k}=F_{k-1}t_{0}+F_{k}t_{1}=\lceil A^{n-1}/\sqrt{5}\rceil t_{0}+ \lceil A^{n}/\sqrt{5}\rceil t_{1}
\tag{2}$$
Despite not knowing whether this is the way to answer this problem, I am stuck at here since I don't know how to deal with logarithm of a ceiling. I would truly appreciate any assistance.

Not following.  This is the usual Fibonacci recursion, right?  It's determined uniquely by $T_0, T_1$...so how can you also specify $T_n$?

@lulu you are correct, I fixed this minor mistake. We only know $n$ and $T_{n}$.

Well, but then the sequence is not determined.  You need two values.

@lulu Indeed, but such sequence can be constructed by only knowing $T_{n}$ and $n$ which is the length of this sequence. This was the topic of my last question which I received some excellent answers.

No, it can't.  Given $T_{10}=329$, to pick random values, we can define $T_9$ to be any value you like and get the rest of the values that.   Well, requiring all the $T_n$ to be positive integers imposes some conditions.

I don't think it is possible to obtain a fibonacci-like sequence of length $10$ whose $n-$th term is $329$ provided that $T_{i}\in\mathbb{N}$ and are positive. @lulu from a python implementation I made, if given $n=5$, $T_{5}=329$, then you can construct a sequence with parameters $T_{0}=14$ and $T_{1}=7$

Yes, the natural numbers constraint is tougher than I thought.  But...can you prove uniqueness where the solution exists?

Oh, no you can't.  If $T_3=5$ then you could have $T_1, T_2= (1,4)$ or $=(2,3)$.  So you have problems both with existence and with uniqueness.

How familiar are you with recurrence relations? We have the general solution $T_i  =  A \phi ^i + B \phi^{-i} $, so $ T_n / T_ 0 \approx \phi^n$. This should be good enough to estimate $ \log_{10} { T_ 0} $. $\quad$ There could be a potential issue if $ A = 0 $, but in which case $T_n$ is a decreasing sequence of integers, so eventually so $T_k < 0 $ which is disallowed. $\quad$ EG For $T_{10} = 329$, $329 /  \phi^{10} \approx 2.67$, which is within a magnitude of 7.

I see uniqueness is not guaranteed at least due to the number of ways we can add the same natural numbers together. I couldn't think of this simple example you made before @lulu

So before your question could be well-posed you would have to show that the number of digits is independent of your choice of sequence (given the constraints), at least asymptotically.  Not sure that's true, but it might be.

(Continuing my comment) The other issue could be when $|B| >> A$, which results in a  $T_0 > T_1$ like lulu's (randomly?) chosen example. In which case, the approximation of $ T_0 = A$ is not appropriate and we actually have $T_0 \approx B$. Unfortunately, in such a scenario, we have no control over $T_n / T_0$. The saving grace is that since $T_0 > 0$, $ |B| < A \phi^2$. In this case, we can take $ T_0$ approximately between $ T_n / \phi^n, T_n / \phi^{n-2} $. These numbers are in a ratio of $ \phi^2 \approx 2.6$, that's close! $\quad$ EG For $T_{10} = 329, 329 / \phi ^ 8 \approx 7.00$.

@CalvinLin I wrote a program that does a sanity check based on these bounds. For $T_{n}=9523$, one possible solution is $n=11$, $T_{0}=89$, and $T_{1}=52$. with bounds $[47.85,125.28]$ which seems to be very wide.

Yup. I know where i made a mistake with not considering enough issues. You do have a wide range, because we can add/subtract $(F_k, F_{k-1} )$ accordingly. However, we can still make some restrictions.

@Kamola For your $T_5 = 329$ example, we have $T_0 = 14, T_1 = 7, T_2 = 21, T_3 = 28, T_4 = 49, T_5 = 77, T_6 = 126, T_8 = 203, T_9 = 329$, so you should mean $n= 9$?

Note also that $329 = F_7 \times 14 + F_8 \times 7$, so your equation 2 is off by an index. For these reasons, my post is off by an index.

[We assume, per the comments, that $T_0, T_1 \geq 0$, even though technically positivity is only defined on $k > 1$. ]
Observe that  $T_k = F_{k-2} T_0 + F_{k-1} T_1$. (See Note 1 for details.)
How can we solve this linear diophantine equation?
We first consider all integers solutions, before restricting to the positive solutions.
The standard approach is to solve for $ F_{k-2} x + F_{k-1} y = \gcd(F_{k-2}, F_{k-1}) = 1$. Because these are the Fibonacci numbers, apart form knowing that solutions exist, we actually can explicitly construct them since we have the identify $F_{k-2}F_{k-2} - F_{k-1} F_{k-3} = (-1)^{k-1}$.
Hence, a particular solution is $(T_0, T_1) = \left( (-1)^{k-1}F_{k-2}T_k, (-1)^{k} F_{k-3}T_k \right)$, and the general solution is
$$(T_0, T_1) = \left( (-1)^{k-1}F_{k-2}T_k + m F_{k-1},\quad  (-1)^{k} F_{k-3}T_k - mF_{k-2} \right),  m \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Now, we concern ourselves with non-negative integer solutions. Note that we're not guaranteed that non-negative integer solutions exist, esp if $T_k$ is too small. By the chicken nugget theorem, we are guaranteed non-negative solutions if $ T_k >   F_{k-2} F_{k-1} - F_{k-2} - F_{k-1} = T_k^*  $.  For values below this, exactly one of $T_k$ or $T_k^* - T_k$ will work.
Case 1: If $k$ is odd, then

$T_0 \geq 0 \Rightarrow m \geq -\lfloor \frac{F_{k-2} T_k}{F_{k-1}} \rfloor  $
$T_1 \geq 0 \Rightarrow m \leq - \lceil \frac{ F_{k-3} T_k } { F_{k-2} } \rceil$.
Hence, if $ -\lfloor \frac{F_{k-2} T_k}{F_{k-1}} \rfloor \leq - \lceil \frac{ F_{k-3} T_k } { F_{k-2} } \rceil$, then the minimum $T_0$ is obtained at the former, and the maximum $T_0$ is obtained at the latter. Else, no solution exists.

Case 2: If $k$ is even, then

$T_0 \geq 0 \Rightarrow m \geq \lceil \frac{F_{k-2}T_k}{F_{k-1}} \rceil$
$T_1 \geq 0 \Rightarrow m \leq \lfloor \frac{F_{k-3}T_k}{F_{k-2}} \rfloor$
Hence, if $ \lceil \frac{F_{k-2}T_k}{F_{k-1}} \rceil \leq \lfloor \frac{F_{k-3}T_k}{F_{k-2}} \rfloor $, then the minimum $T_0$ is obtained at the former, and the maximum $T_0$ is obtained at the latter. Else, no solution exists.

Thus, we have a complete classification of the solution sets, and hence can find the min/max number of digits.

Let's check against some of the cases listed in the comments.

$T_9 = 329$: Unique solution $T_0 = 14, T_1 = 7$.

$F_8 = 21, F_7 = 13, F_6 = 8$.
We can visually verify that $329 = 13 \times 14 + 21 \times 7$ is the unique solution non-negative solution.
We have the particular solution $(13 \times 329, -8 \times 329)$ and the general solution $(13 \times 329 + m \times 21, -8 \times 329 - m \times 13)$.
Check the condition $-203 =  -\lfloor \frac{F_{k-2} T_k}{F_{k-1}} \rfloor \leq - \lceil \frac{ F_{k-3} T_k } { F_{k-2} } \rceil = -203$. And indeed, substituting in $m = -203$ gives us $(14, 7)$.


$T_{10} = 329$: No solution

(We can verify the claim by taking one step backward from the $T_9 = 329$ solution and get the solution $(-7, 14)$ which unfortunately isn't in non-negative integers)
$F_9 = 34, F_8 = 21, F_7 = 13$.
We have the particular solution $(21 \times 329, -13 \times 329)$ and the general solution $(21 \times 329 + m\times 34, -13 \times 329 - m \times 21)$
Check the condition $ 204 = \lceil \frac{21 \times 329 }{34} \rceil \leq \lfloor \frac{13 \times 329}{21} \rfloor =203 $ is not satisfied, hence no solution exists.




Note

$$T_k = F_2 T_{k-2} + F_1 T_{k-1} = F_3 T_{k-3} + F_2 T_{k-2} = \ldots = F_{k-2} T_0 + F_{k-1 } T_1 .$$

